# Pandas countifs value from column and other column not null

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to perform the equivalent to an Excel COUNTIFS formula in pandas, where the first range is a dataframe column, and the search criteria is each value in that column. The second search range is a different column and the criteria is non null values in that column.

Written as an Excel formula, it would look like: COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>")

Here is some sample data:

```
data = {'ADJL':['BCF-364/BTS-1091/ADJL-4', 'BCF-130/BTS-389/ADJL-1', 'BCF-130/BTS-389/ADJL-1', 'BCF-130/BTS-389/ADJL-1', 'BCF-130/BTS-389/ADJL-1', 'BCF-130/BTS-389/ADJL-1', 'BCF-581/BTS-1742/ADJL-1', 'BCF-581/BTS-1742/ADJL-1'], 
        'LNCEL':['LNBTS-55/LNCEL-63', '', 'LNBTS-801/LNCEL-62', '', 'LNBTS-801/LNCEL-61', '', '', '']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I need to add two columns to this. The first is a count of the value of each "ADJL". I found this solution for that column:

```
df['Count_of_ADJL'] = df.groupby('ADJL')['ADJL'].transform('Count_of_ADJL')
```

What I am stuck on is the next one, shown below in Excel. I need to calculate how many times the value in ADJL occurs throughout the entire ADJL column AND the LNCEL column is not empty. 
I removed many other columns to simplify my question, so a solution where I can just add another column is ideal.

[image]

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby.transform` with `np.count_nonzero` as:

```
df['Count_of_ADJL'] = df.groupby('ADJL')['ADJL'].transform('count')
df['Count_of_ADJL & LNCEL not null'] = df.groupby('ADJL')['LNCEL'].transform(np.count_nonzero)
#or
df['Count_of_ADJL & LNCEL not null'] = df.groupby('ADJL')['LNCEL'].transform('count')

print(df)
                      ADJL               LNCEL  Count_of_ADJL  \
0  BCF-364/BTS-1091/ADJL-4   LNBTS-55/LNCEL-63              1   
1   BCF-130/BTS-389/ADJL-1                                  5   
2   BCF-130/BTS-389/ADJL-1  LNBTS-801/LNCEL-62              5   
3   BCF-130/BTS-389/ADJL-1                                  5   
4   BCF-130/BTS-389/ADJL-1  LNBTS-801/LNCEL-61              5   
5   BCF-130/BTS-389/ADJL-1                                  5   
6  BCF-581/BTS-1742/ADJL-1                                  2   
7  BCF-581/BTS-1742/ADJL-1                                  2   

   Count_of_ADJL & LNCEL not null  
0                               1  
1                               2  
2                               2  
3                               2  
4                               2  
5                               2  
6                               0  
7                               0
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sandeep, that is exactly what I was looking for.  The 'Count_of_ADJL & LNCEL not null' method gave me the same results as the 'Count_of_ADJL' but the second one, with .transform('count') works wonderfully.
Again, your help is much appreciated.